# overflow-x:hidden on body tag...good idea/bad idea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a client that keeps wanting more and more control of their own css. My company could care less. But they keep breaking the margins with padding L/R: 29% and margin L/R: 3vw...stuff like that. Whenever they break something I get the email to fix it.
The question is that so far all the issues have just been padding percentages and margins. It doesn't affect the content of the page. If i just add on the  tag overflow-x:hidden, that will fix my problem forever, right? Can someone let me know of downsides/problems before I make change on production site?

Comment: If the content is not responsive, it might be sort of cut off when window resizes to a smaller resolution?

Comment: If they have control over CSS they can just do `overflow-x:auto !important`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad idea. It hides real content potentially, and will eventually create problems with readability and responsivity, it allows for images and text leaving the viewport halfways and is in general bad for accessibility. It won't adapt well on tiny screens.

It looks like you need to frame the whole page in a container, use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include padding and borders when document width (and height) is calculated by the browser, and give the container a max-width of 100% or `100vw` so that nothing overflows. Then your client can add as much padding and margins in there as they want to.

Maybe you can try to use position: relative for most of the elements in the container so that they know to size themselves relative to the container, which makes it less likely that something overflows. Also, set max-width 100% on images and text elements, and add `word-break: break-all;` on text elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

Last but not least, make sure the initial-width in  is correctly set to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to make sure the zoom level is right on all devices.